# QR Code reader on Appcelerator/Titanium/Alloy?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, qr-code, titanium-alloy

I would like to create a qr code reader on my iphone/android app developed with alloy framework on appcelerator platform.

It seems that every modules that i've checked are deprecated or simply not working.. i'd like to know if there is something open source that is working on the newer sdk versions (>=5.5.1)

If anyone have an idea or a tips to help me..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you should tell which ones you tried / are not working to prevent anyone posting the ones you already tried

Answer (score 1):

you'll find the good release for SDK 7 here :
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.barcode/releases

Answer (score 0):

I use the following modules, currently work with 5.5.1

Android : com.acktie.mobile.android.qr - https://github.com/acktie/Acktie-Mobile-Android-QR-Reader

iOS : ti.barcode - https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.barcode/releases/download/ios-1.9.1/ti.barcode-iphone-1.9.1.zip